# what is no. of positive eigen value of symmetric matrix A with some given relationship

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A is a 3*3  symmetric matrix s.t.

$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1 \\ 
 \end{pmatrix} A  \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ 
y\\
1\end{pmatrix}  = xy -1 $$

let p be the no. of positive eigen value of A and q = rank(A)-p, then
p=? q=?

what matrix A should be I can't find??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** I would try brute force, if you have no other idea, i.e. take an arbitrary symmetric $3\times 3$-matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\b&d&e\\c&e&f\end{pmatrix}$. Then compute the left hand side and compare coefficients to the right hand side. You get a system of easy linear equations that you can solve.

**Added:** As @HenningMakholm showed for a [Duplicate of this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/523518/3111), solving for the entries of symmetric $A$ gives:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

a block diagonal form as promised in the Comment below.  The upper $2\times 2$ block has one positive and one negative eigenvalue, $\pm \frac{1}{2}$, and the lower block obviously has one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: @Prasanta You can make the problem a bit easier by noting that $A$ has block diagonal form. So you only have to care about the upper $2\times 2$-block.