# No. of positive eigen values of $3\times 3$ real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix such that  :

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 1 
 \end{pmatrix} A  \begin{pmatrix} a  \\ 
b\\
1\end{pmatrix}  = ab -1$$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

Question is to find no. of positive eigen values of $A$. and rank of $A$.

What i have observed so far is  :

- As $A$ is symmetric matrix, it should have real eigen values. item
- As $x^TAx$ is not positive, for $x= \begin{pmatrix} a  \\ 
  b\\
  1\end{pmatrix}$, ($a=b=\frac{1}{2}$) we see that not  all eigen values of $A$ are positive
- As $x^TAx$ is not negative, for $x= \begin{pmatrix} a  \\ 
  b\\
  1\end{pmatrix}$, ($a=2,b=1$) we see that not  all eigen values of $A$ are Negative

So, $A$ does have positive eigen values and also negative eigen values.

Now, I have little less clarity particularly here :

If i take $a=b=1$ the, I have 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix} A  \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 
1\\
1\end{pmatrix}  = 1 -1=0$$

I want to conlcude from this that $$ A  \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 
1\\
1\end{pmatrix}  =0\begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 
1\\
1\end{pmatrix}$$ somehow converting row marrix in one side to column matrix in other side.

If this is true, then i would have $0$ as one eigen value.

So, I have one positive, one negative, one $0$ eigen value.

So, Rank of $A$ should be $2$ and no. of positive eigen values is $1$.

Please help me to sort out some mistakes (if there are any) and help me to make this answer a little messier than what i have written.

This problem is already asked some time ago but, the answer for that was "to try with a  brute force" which i thought is not the only way to go.

I had some start up but that is not entire answer, so i can not post that as an answer there..

So, I thought i should ask here at the risk of getting negative votes.

P.S : Here is the link for a copy of this [what is no. of positive eigen value of symmetric matrix A with some given relationship](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426719/what-is-no-of-positive-eigen-value-of-symmetric-matrix-a-with-some-given-relati?rq=1)

Comment: The problem is that you can't simply go from $x^TAx=0$ to $Ax=0$.

Comment: @egreg : Yes, Yes.. I see that problem.. I have no other idea to go any further...

Comment: The context of "to try with brute force" in [the previous Question's Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426719/what-is-no-of-positive-eigen-value-of-symmetric-matrix-a-with-some-given-relati?rq=1) was to use variables for the entries of $A$ and use the condition on the quadratic form $v^T A v$ to determine those entries.  As Henning shows more explicitly, with symmetry of $A$, this approach succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

The condition
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 1 
 \end{pmatrix} A  \begin{pmatrix} a  \\ 
b\\
1\end{pmatrix}  = ab -1$$
for all $a$ and $b$ implies that $A$ must have the form
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & p & q \\ 1-p & 0 & r \\ -q & -r & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
(consider the nine elements of $A$ as unknowns, and equate coefficients in the polynomials in $a$ and $b$ on each side of the equation).

There is only one set of values for $p$, $q$ and $r$ that make $A$ symmetric. Now that you know $A$ explicitly, you can compute its rank, eigenvalues, etc. directly.

---

If this is too simple for you, you can also multiply your equation by $z^2$ to find
$$\begin{pmatrix} za & zb & z 
 \end{pmatrix} A  \begin{pmatrix} za  \\ zb\\ z\end{pmatrix}  = abz^2 - z^2$$
and then for a nonzero $z$ and arbitrary $x$ and $y$ set $a=x/z$ and $b=y/z$ to find
$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z 
 \end{pmatrix} A  \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}  = xy - z^2$$
which by continuity of each side must also hold for $z=0$. Now you have the quadratic form written down explicitly in full generality, and it is trivial to write it down as a symmetric matrix $A$. Again its eigenvalues and -vectors are then easy to find directly.

Comment: I don't want to compute explicitly what are the eigen values rather, I want to use more theory to conclude something about the given question.. Anyways Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Praphulla: Knowing $A$ explicitly would at least prevent you from trying to prove falsehoods such as $A(1~1~1)^T=0$.

Comment: Yes, Yes... I totally  agree with your view and thanks for clarifying that $(1 1 1)^T$ is not eigen vector corresponding to $0$ (if 0  is actually an eigen value)